# How to create a meta_query to get all posts with a specific meta data?

Tags: post-meta, meta-query

Here are the args for my query :

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'vendor',
                'value' => 'farsi',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
    )
    );
```

This doesn't work when topics is a string, it gets me all products, But I need to get all products that have meta data (vendor) `farsi`.

UPDATE:

i use this code that move out of stock products to last product in archive:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'move_out_of_stock_products_to_end' );
```

When stop it, the query work good.

So what can do !!

Comment: Are you sure vendor is the meta_key and not wpcf-vendor? Please check in database and confirm.

Comment: yes i check it in database

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target meta key `vendor` and meta value `farsi`, you need to pass the following `meta_query` arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'vendor',
            'value'   => 'farsi',
        )
    )
);
```

Also to note, as Jiten highlighted, your meta key may be `wpcf-vendor`.

Comment: i try and get me `HTTP ERROR 500 `

Comment: That error is not related to this particular code. Learn more about 500 [here](https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938).

Comment: thank you.. now its same my code,, its get me all product have vendor farsi and null and empty ... !!